# Restrict views to specific languages

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

Using the locale modul (core) and [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) it is possible to show a language switcher, which will guide the user to corresponding nodes in another language. In case of views, this language switcher points to a view in every language. The views path i.e.

www.website.com/path/to/view

gets "translated" to every language

www.website.com/language-path/path/to/view.

Is it possible to change this behaviour or to restrict the view to specific languages?

Comment: Something like redirect using: http://drupal.org/project/redirect ?!

Comment: I dont want to redirect the user after visiting the view in another language, but alter the links shown in the language switcher.

Comment: how do you tell the view what language is should be ?

Comment: I dont know :) Thats why im asking! I know it is possible to filter for the users current language. Thats good, so at least the user doesn´t see totally confusing content, but in my case there are languages with no content to show in the view, so i want to somehow disable the view in this language.

Comment: Sorry, I don't clearly understand what you're asking. Is it hiding the language switcher if the view has no result in the other language ? Please explain :)

Comment: What do you mean by "change this behaviour" ? If you want to map different urls corresponding to the same view in different languages, this answer will help you : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53175/how-can-i-have-a-multilingual-url-for-a-views-result-page-depending-on-the-langu/53204#53204

Comment: ... Or you could just filter your view for the user's current language + set "No results behavior" to display a particular node (404 or other)

Comment: @bsfoo116 i wish i could give the bounty to your comment!!! Thanks a lot! One last thing, do you know how to include a placeholder in this path?

Comment: With PhP field, you can use PhP in this path and use $global->language to set deisgnated path as you wish

Comment: @GregoryKapustin i dont understand your comment :( Could you please explain a little further? I meant in the translation sets. In my case i have a "news/%" view with placeholder in the path, so i would like to include every path like this in the translation set, but i can´t figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to map different URLs** corresponding to the same view in different languages, [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/53204) will help you. Basically you have to enable "Translation sets" and "Path translation" modules, both part of i18n module. Then in `admin/config/regional/i18n_translation/path`, add the translated paths and then add a "translation set" which will map all these pages together.

**If you want to restrict the view to specific languages** because it yields no results for the other languages, you can filter your view results by the user's current language and set a "No results behaviour" to display the view results for a different (default) language, using a `Global: View area`. See [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/91422) for more details. Of course you can also display a specific node (404 page or other) as a "No results behaviour".

@jumper: I've put this answer in case you want to give the bounty :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited your answer a little bit to include the actual solution right here.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can restrict the views language by adding filter criteria for content:language if you want to restrict it based on the content language or by user:language if you want to restrict/filter it based on the preferred language for the current logged user

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I dont want to change the view depending on the users language, but hide the view in specific languages.

Comment: then you should add the filter criteria Content:Language which will filter the view content for a specific language, which mean if you don't have any content for that language it will return an empty view, but if you want to hide the entire view page for a specific language, you can install "Rules" Module and create a rule that will redirect the user to another page (which you you chose) basing your conditions on for that language and the path to the view.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use [Select Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_translation).**

If your view is meant to show nodes, and your nodes use the Content Translation* mechanism, you can install the Select Translation module. It provides a filter "Content translation: Select translation" by which you can define a fallback mechanism to select which language version of results should be used.

For example, you can specify that if a result is not available in the current language, its English version is used. So if *no* results are available for the current language, [as in your case](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62617/restrict-views-to-specific-languages#comment68321_62617), this is equivalent to visiting the English version of the view. So effectively this "restricts the view to specific languages" resp. "hides the view in specific languages" as you [asked](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62617/restrict-views-to-specific-languages) [for](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62617/restrict-views-to-specific-languages/63437#comment68880_63401).

**Content Translation:* That's the default translation mechanism in Drupal 7, available in Core. So if you did not install the alternative ([Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation)), you are using this one.

Answer (score 0):

**You can rewrite the language filter in custom code.**

I [know](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62617/restrict-views-to-specific-languages#comment68321_62617) you only want to modify the view if it has no content to show in the selected language. Here's a solution that can do that, but also allows you to modify the view results *even if* there are results in the currently selected language:

1. Add a language filter to your view:

   - If you use [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation), add the "Content: Language" filter.
   - If you use Content Translation, add the "Content Translation: Language" filter.
   - If you use Content Translation and want automatic language fallback behaviour for each result, you can use the "Content translation: Select translation" filter instead, provided by the [Select Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_translation) module.
2. Implement `hook_views_query_alter()` and change the parameters of your language filter as needed. For details, see [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/26456/16305). For example, you can implement logic such as "If the current language is Chinese, set the language filter to show English content".