# How to show, in a view, content depending on user language or default?

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

In one of my [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), showing a preview of some nodes, how can I set the nodes to be shown to be the ones in the user language or, if the user has no language set or is anonymous or the language is not set for the node, the ones in the site default languages?

I can do the two thing with 'filter criteria' separately but not together...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Internationalizations Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module, which extends the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module with multilingual support for views.

Also, to make view results correspond to the language switcher, add a filter for **Content Translation: User's Current Language**, which is the language that an authenticated user has set in the user settings (it is NOT the same as the current browser language or the site language).

If no option for the **User's Current Language** is available in the filter criteria form, then verify your configuration at *Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection*: The order should be **URL, Default, User** and not something like **Default, URL, User** (as mentioned also in https://www.drupal.org/node/1701854#comment-6279474).

**Notes**:

- The above may turn out to NOT be the complete answer. You may use the [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module and, in that case, there is not this option if you use it in 'entity' mode: if only some fields of the node are translatable the option is there but a bit more difficult to find. If you have the 'Body' of your nodes set to translatable entity then the option is "Body language" to be set to Current User Language.
- The [Internationalizations Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module only has a **DEV** version for D7, but right now there are [over 31K users using this version](https://www.drupal.org/project/usage/i18nviews). Therefor I think "DEV" is not a valid release qualifier for that version anymore, because *+31K users can't be wrong*, right?

Comment: After three days this turned to be the right answer. Not completely though. I was forced (for some reasons of mine, not for the sake of this solution) to use Entity Translation and, in that case, there is not this option if you use it in 'entity' mode. I mean that if only some fields of the node are translatable the option is there but a bit more difficult to find. I had the 'Body' of my nodes set to translatable entity and the option was "Body language" to be set to Current User Language. Do you think you can add this detail to the answer? I found a lot of people struggling about this...

Comment: ...and took me three days to figure it out. So it would be great to add it to the right answer!

Comment: Thanks for the (great) extra feedback (and accept of course ...). Hang on a few minutes to let me (try to) integrate your comment above in my answer also ... PS: i18n can be complicated ... views also and putting them together is making it even tougher, no?

Comment: Please QA-read my expanded answer (1st bullet in "note" now), and let me know if there is anything that needs further refinement/correction (or suggest an edit yourself and I'll approve it, so that you'll get a +2 rep for it also).

Comment: Seems perfect to me! Hope it will save someone else times. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you can't find the "Content Translation: Language" filter: this is treated in [another question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/158436/16305).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Select Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_translation) module to configure language fallback behaviour for Views results.

This is esp. useful when the "Content Translation: Language" filter is not available, which is needed for [@Pierre's solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/178726/16305). This happens when you have Entity Translation enabled in addition to Content Translation [[details](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/207874/16305)].