# Drupal multilingual monthly archive using views

Tags: views

I have multilingual website in Drupal 7 and I am trying to implement news and monthly archive by using views. I am facing some problems with the monthly archive (I am cloning the default Archive).

For each language I have created news pages - f.ex. www.mywebsite.com/news (in English) and www.mywebsite.com/da/nyheder (in Danish). I also have created different views ("news", "monthly archive") for each language. The switch between the news including the views "news" works fine. But the switch between the monthly archives does not work in the way that I would like to. For example when I am on the page www.mywebsite.com/news/201301 and switch to Danish I am going to the page www.mywebsite.com/da/news/201301 but I would like to go www.mywebsite.com/da/nyheder/201301.

In every view I am specifying the language (content language and field language) to English or Danish. Any idea how I can solve the path problem?

I have also tried to use one view for news and one view for monthly archive (using current user's language) but then the problem is the title page. I can not translate the title for the different languages (accessibility issue).

Can somebody explane which is the right way for implementation of news monthly archive for multilingual website please.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following similar question - [How can I have a multilingual URL for a views result page depending on the language?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53175/how-can-i-have-a-multilingual-url-for-a-views-result-page-depending-on-the-langu?rq=1) help? It suggests the use of path translations and translations sets (part of [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) which I assume you already have installed and configured)?